# Почему пакеты в java принято называть в обратную сторону доменного имени?

Tags: java, package

То что это делать надо именно так, везде написано. Но почему люди договорились называть именно так? Может быть в этом есть какое-то неочевидное удобство?

Comment: вопрос, скорее, обратный: почему в доменных именах их части записывают в обратном порядке — начиная с менее значимого. ответ достаточно очевидный: такова традиция — записывать доменные имена «наизнанку» (сравните с ситуацицей, в которой «сто двадцать три» записывали бы как «321»). а в именах пакетов части имени записаны как раз в логическом порядке.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Уникальные имена в глобальном масштабе исключают конфликты имен между библиотеками из разных источников. Вместо создания новой центральной базы данных глобальных имен используется реестр доменных имен.

Java Language Specification (JLS):

> The suggested convention for generating unique package names is merely a way to piggyback a package naming convention on top of an existing, widely known unique name registry instead of having to create a separate registry for package names.

Представь, что у тебя есть например четыре важных пакета и ты напишешь их так:

```
 package controller.mysite.org;
 package model.mysite.org;
 package service.mysite.org;
 package dao.mysite.org;
```

Это означает, что существует основной пакет, подраздел которого относится к твоей компании (имя твоего ресурса), а подраздел этого пакета называется пакетом org, который ты фактически используешь и он есть уникальный. 
Но если написать так:

```
 package org.mysite.controller;
 package org.mysite.model;
 package org.mysite.service;
 package org.mysite.dao;
```

Эта запись имеет больший смысл. Из всех пакетов из организаций (org) ты, смотришь на имя своей компании, и у нее есть четыре подпакета: `controller`, `model`, `service`, `dao`.

Comment: Из примеров, кстати, неплохо видно, почему выгодно сонаправить направление вложенности пакетов с направлением текста: импорты нескольких смежных пакетов выглядят связанными без дополнительного выравнивания, просто за счёт размещения на соседних строчках.

Answer (score 9):

Есть, хотя и довольно очевидное, оно [неплохо изложено в документации к Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html):

> Компании используют в начале имён своих пакетов своё развёрнутое доменное имя, например `com.example.mypackage`, означающий пакет `mypackage`, созданный программистом из `example.com`.
>
> Коллизии между пакетами в пределах одной компании должны разрешаться внутри самой компании, например добавлением к доменному имени компании региона или названия проекта, на манер `com.example.region.mypackage`.

В общем, снижает вероятность коллизий между именами пакетов. А когда они всё-таки случаются, минимизируют ущерб, количество и удалённость вовлечённых сторон.

Разумеется, никто не заставляет этим конвенциям следовать. Но сами разработчики в первую очередь заинтересованы в том, чтобы их пакеты не конфликтовали с чужими.

Comment: Совершенно не очевидно, чем `mypackage.example.com` было бы хуже

Comment: @avp это бы, например, начало путать в головах у людей порядок в путях файловой системы (напоминаю, что каждый `.`-сегмент пакета представляется папкой) и в названиях пакетов. Реального ответа я, разумеется, не знаю, это design decision языка. Могли решить иначе. Вышел бы другой набор косяков :)

Answer (score 5):

Имена пакетов - это структура папок. Именование идет от общего к частному: у региона имеются компании, у компаний - подразделения, у них проекты, в проектах классы и тд.

То есть, корневая папка объеденяет общий домен, в которой "сложены" компании, в папке каждой компании - ее проекты ... это наиболее логичная структура