# Подскажите по файлу APK

Tags: android, apk

в манифесте прописано

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto"
 package="site.boardfix.app" platformBuildVersionCode="23" 
platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2704002">
```

1. Т.е если у меня сайт domen.ru, то package="ru.domen.app"  ? Почему меняется местами имя домена с его доменной зоной?
2. У меня кириллический домен , если вставляю его пуникод, то выходит ошибка при компиляции

   **Tag  attribute package has invalid character '-' Android Manifest**

а если ставлю русскими символами, то та же ошибка, но символ "@" Как это можно решить ?

Comment: 2. В общем, никак. [Требования к package name](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html) не дают указывать в нём ни punycode, ни IDN'ы. И не задавайте по нескольку вопросов в одном.

Answer (score 4):

Здесь нужно указывать не адрес вашего сайта, а имя пакета приложения, которое в общем случае не имеет никакого отношения к сайту. Единственное требование к нему - уникальность (в одной системе не должно быть двух приложений с одинаковым именем пакета).

Принято указывать имя пакета в виде обратного доменного имени по ряду причин, основная из которых - группировка по "уменьшающемуся" признаку, обычно это: регион.название компании.название приложения, то есть в папке региона будут компании этого региона, в папке компаний - их проекты.

Вам не нужно выдумывать какие то сложности в выборе этих имен. Пишите латиницей и забутье о URL вашего сайта, главное, чтобы никто не составил такую же комбинацию, иначе будет конфликт пакетов.

[Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728735/177345)