# Как назвать пакет в android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Насколько я понял, имя пакета  - это адрес моего сайта наоборот. Но что мне делать если у меня нет сайта?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728735/177345

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нету такого правила. Исторически ноги растут [отсюда](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions).

Главное, чтоб application id был уникальным. Как правило, это что-то такое `com.companyname.applicationname`.

Это никак с сайтом не связано. Просто так уж сложилось, что, к примеру, у тех же Adobe сайт https://www.adobe.com, поэтому application id у, например, ридера - `com.adobe.reader`.

Answer (score 3):

называйте как угодно: `com.mypackage.myproject` Это уникальное имя вашего проекта, оно мало на что повлияет. Единственное, учитывайте, если вы назовете пакет `com.example.*` - вы не сможете опубликовать приложение на GooglePlay.