# Почему не импортируется интерфейс во внутренние пакеты

Tags: java, интерфейс

В main есть интерфейс "Sedan".
также есть пакет в main под названием "Toyota", в котором есть класс ToyotaSedan который должен имплементить интерфейс Sedan из main, но импорт не происходит, вручную пишу тоже самое... (пс не только он не имплементиться, все интерфейсы из маин)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что в седане написано, может метод надо реализовать? и что ide пишет?

Comment: public interface Sedan {
} больше ничего, иде красным выделяет и пишет что поискать депендаси

Comment: пустой интерфейс?

Comment: следуй подсказкам ide

Comment: пустой интерфейс

Comment: не находит пишет not found

Comment: даже если пишу implements в подсказках нет интерфейса Sedan из Main

Comment: нажми alt+enter и следуй подсказкам ide... а что значит импорт не происходит?

Comment: при alt+enter подсказки либо поискать зависимости, либо создать интерфейс, но интерфейс то есть. Если создавать в пакете то все норм видит, а из майна не видит. пишу вручную import Sedan; таже истоиря

Comment: в папке java(которая синего цвета) создай пакет, название своего проекта, и уже в нём разбивай на пакеты... в этом и проблема, т.к. в корне у тебя интерфейс

Comment: Супер. Спасибо. Значит в корне интерфейс создавать нельзя?

Comment: есть правила структкры приложения именования пакетов...https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728735/Почему-пакеты-в-java-принято-называть-в-обратную-сторону-доменного-имени

Comment: Нет кода нет ответа 